# AutoDesk Forge Data Viz Application

Tags: node.js, npm, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to run the forge-dataviz-reference-app from their website, and I was following the directions from their website (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/running_the_application/) and whenever I would run

```
cd forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app
npm install
```

I would receive pages of npm error messages, including:

```
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/subset_map.cpp:2:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/to_c.cpp:3:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/to_value.cpp:2:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Has this happened to anyone else and if so does anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Can you give more details about your configuration ? OS, NodeJS version, NPM version ? I tried with Node 14.18.0(npm 6.14.15) without any error. Then I switched to Node 16.10.0 (npm 7.24.0) and I got errors similar to yours.

Comment: On the GitHub repo, there is an issue opened. It's seems there is some problem using node version > 15, which confirms what I tried. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/issues/10 You should try with a node v15.

Comment: AlexAR, you are my hero. I did what you recommended and it worked perfectly. I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This project is based on the node.js v15. If you use node.js v16 and above, please change the `node-sass` version referencing in the `package.json`. For example, for node.js v16, the `node-sass` version should be `^6.0.0`.

Here is a quick guide for minimum and maximum supported versions of [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) from its repo.

| NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node 17 | 7.0+ | 102 |
| Node 16 | 6.0+ | 93 |
| Node 15 | 5.0+, <7.0 | 88 |
| Node 14 | 4.14+ | 83 |
| Node 13 | 4.13+, <5.0 | 79 |
| Node 12 | 4.12+, <8.0 | 72 |
| Node 11 | 4.10+, <5.0 | 67 |
| Node 10 | 4.9+, <6.0 | 64 |
| Node 8 | 4.5.3+, <5.0 | 57 |
| Node <8 | <5.0 | <57 |

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Have a nice day Eason!